# Blog in magento subdirectory not working without index.php

Tags: wordpress, magento, nginx, url-rewriting

I have magento hosted on `nginx`.I have installed wordpress in magento roor directory.

I have my blog url like `www.mymagento.com/blog` and blog post urls are like `www.mymagento.com/blog/page/2/`.

The blogpost urls pages are working fine. But when I go to `www.mymagento.com/blog`.

The page structure is messed up.

If I enable **Use Web Server Rewrites** to no in magento admin, everything workes well.

This is www.mymagento.com dummy url.

How can I fix this issue please help.

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in .htaccess of www.mymagento.com/blog, clean browser history and try again:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that will help you!

Comment: .htaccess is only for Apache servers.